# Get "allow email" attribute of quote status entry via apex

Tags: apex, quote, status

Under setup, when defining quote status you're allowed to check a box that says "allow email" on the individual status. I need to get the value of this property per status in apex:

[Schema.PickListEntry](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_PicklistEntry.htm#apex_class_Schema_PicklistEntry) doesn't seem to have any methods that Can be used to get this.

I also looked at the WSDL to see if there was a hidden field at the quote level that I could use (such as IsClosed on case) and could not find anything.

Is there a way to get whether or not "allow email" is enabled for a specified status?

Comment: I don't think so, but you could probably just setWhatId for the quote, and try sending the email; you'll get an exception if it's not allowed, if my understanding is correct.

Comment: We were hoping to add more than just email limitations based on that check box. I have the status values hardcoded right now, would just like to not have to do that.

Comment: This took me *way-y-y-y-y* too long to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with this, it seems like you need to get a hold of the StandardValueSet, which is available in the Tooling API and Metadata API. You can get to the tooling API by using a query:

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v43.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+Metadata+FROM+StandardValueSet+WHERE+MasterLabel%3D\'QuoteStatus\'');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer '+UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setMethod('GET');
String result = new Http().send(req).getBody();
```

Note that this is a JSON response, the output will look like this:

```
{
    "done": true,
    "entityTypeName": "StandardValueSet",
    "queryLocator": null,
    "records": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "StandardValueSet",
                "url": "/services/data/v43.0/tooling/sobjects/StandardValueSet/QuoteStatus"
            },
            "Metadata": {
                "groupingStringEnum": null,
                "sorted": false,
                "standardValue": [
                    {
                        "allowEmail": true,
                        "closed": null,
                        "color": null,
                        "converted": null,
                        "cssExposed": null,
                        "default": true,
                        "description": null,
                        "forecastCategory": null,
                        "groupingString": null,
                        "highPriority": null,
                        "isActive": null,
                        "label": "Draft",
                        "probability": null,
                        "reverseRole": null,
                        "reviewed": null,
                        "urls": null,
                        "valueName": "Draft",
                        "won": null
                    },
                    {
                        "allowEmail": true,
                        "closed": null,
                        "color": null,
                        "converted": null,
                        "cssExposed": null,
                        "default": false,
                        "description": null,
                        "forecastCategory": null,
                        "groupingString": null,
                        "highPriority": null,
                        "isActive": null,
                        "label": "Needs Review",
                        "probability": null,
                        "reverseRole": null,
                        "reviewed": null,
                        "urls": null,
                        "valueName": "Needs Review",
                        "won": null
                    }
                ],
                "urls": null
            }
        }
    ],
    "size": 1,
    "totalSize": 1
}
```

You can also get similar results with the Metadata API, but I don't think it's as convenient.

As usual, you'll need to set up your Remote Site Settings and/or Named Credentials to gain access to the API.